# How to webpack .cshtml views as templateUrl in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, razor, .net-core

I have setup my Angular 2 project in .NET Core solution and I have a situation where I need to use **.cshtml** view files to be rendered from server and use them as templates in Angular components. I am using webpack to **AOT** bundle them.

How can I exclude templateUrl or template to be excluded (not to be compiled into output .js file) but rather resolved on the fly?

My lazy load component (notfound.component.ts):

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    templateUrl: "/Home/PageNotFound" // This is my Controller/Action
})
export class NotFoundComponent
{
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var clean = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
var compression = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
var path = require("path");
var analyzer = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer").BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "app": "./Client/main-aot.ts" // AoT compilation
    },

    devtool: "source-map",

    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/wwwroot/dist/bundle",
        //filename: "[name]-[hash:8].bundle.js",
        filename: "[name].js",
        chunkFilename: "[id]-[hash:8].chunk.js",
        publicPath: "/dist/bundle/",
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [
                    "awesome-typescript-loader",
                    "angular-router-loader?aot=true&genDir=aot/"
                ]
            }
        ],
        exprContextCritical: false
    },
    plugins: [
        new clean(
            [
                __dirname + "/wwwroot/dist/bundle"
            ]
        ),
        new analyzer(),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        minimize: true,
        debug: false
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            },
            output: {
                comments: false
            },
            sourceMap: true
        }),
        new compression({
            asset: "[path].gz[query]",
            algorithm: "gzip",
            test: /\.js$|\.html$/,
            threshold: 10240,
            minRatio: 0.8
        })
    ]
};
```

When I run following NPM command, its giving me error:

**"node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json" && webpack --configebpack.config.js**

**Error: Compilation failed. Resource file not found: 
C:/Users/Saad/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/HelloAngular/HelloAngular/Client/notfound/dist/template/notfound/notfound.html**

Comment: AOT is intended to compile the "angular template" logic and bundle it up as optimised JavaScript, without the inclusion of an engine to parse those templates at runtime. This saves you some space in a build. If you want to use template content rendered on "server requests", then AOT is not for you, since you are going to **need** the runtime engine to interpret the responses. So I think you have a big conceptual understanding to work through.

Comment: Thanks so much Neil. This makes sense and yes I am quite new to Angular 2 and Webpack + AOT.
I was just trying to figure out if there's any way to load MVC views on the fly somehow but I agree AOT is not for this.